# Why form is not submtinig after adding two javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

When i add two function in form everything goes okay but nothing submitted like value=1 or value=2

```
<form method="get" name="formSubmit" onsubmit="return !!(download() & brojac());">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="1" />Razglednica 1<br>
                 </td>
                 <td align="center">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="2" />Razglednica 2<br>
                 </td>
                 <td align="center">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="3"  />Razglednica 3<br>
                 </td>
                 <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="formSubmit" value=" E-MAIL SA SELFIEM" />
                 </form>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to fix code we can't even see? You should probably delete this, read [ask], and start again.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see your `download()` and `brojac()` functions.

Comment: & is bitwise AND. It is not the same as &&! Do you really want to use it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Answer (score 0):

make third function and put both function in it. and then onsubmit call that third function.
put your javascript file for more briefly explanation.